# Eclipse: How to create dynamic web project from existing source?

Tags: eclipse, dynamic, project, web

I'm using Eclipse Indigo on Win XP.  How do I create a dynamic web project from an existing folder?  I went to File -> New -> Project, selected "Dynamic Web Project" in the "New Dynamic Web Project" dialog, but when I selected my existing folder location, I got the error

```
 C:\Documents and Settings\E18538\workspace\cit_pplus_kickoff overlaps the location of another project: 'cit_pplus_kickoff'
```

Here is the dialog -- http://screencast.com/t/Q9VgQKXQ .  How do I create a dynamic web project from existing source?

Edit: When I try and do File -> Import existing projects into workspace, I'm greeted with this error -- http://screencast.com/t/jMwApHh4F ("No projects are found to import").  The directory structure of my project is

src/java
src/java/com
...
src/web
src/web/WEB-INF
src/web/images
...

There is no .project file present.

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new project at the same location as an already existing project. Choose another location for this new project. This new location should be the parent directory of the source folder.

Comment: Hi, I'm still not understanding what your explaining.  When you say "source folder", you're referring to my existing source folder, right?  If so, the folder I chose when creating the new project was the parent directory of the source folder.